# I can not understand the output of this c programming. Please any one help

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int x, y, z;

    x = y = z = 1;
    ++x || ++y && ++z;
    printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
    //op  :   x = 2    y = 1  z = 1 
    //why is 'x' only incrementd? 

    x = y = z = -1;
    ++x || ++y && ++z;
    printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
    //op  :  x = 0    y = 0  z = -1
    //why are 'x' and 'y' incremented?

    x = y = z = 1;
    ++x && ++y || ++z;
    printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
    //op  : x = 2    y = 2  z = 1
    //why is 'x' only incrementd?

    x = y = z = -1;
    ++x && ++y || ++z;
    printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
    //op  : x = 0    y = -1 z = 0
    //why are 'x' and 'z' incremented?

    //Does this incrementation depend on the value stored in the variable?
}
```

Comment: Tip: what does the `||` operator do?

Comment: no my friend asked this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

|| and && short-circuit. What that means is that they perform as little work as possible to return their value, only executing the right side if the left side doesn't nail the answer.

For instance:

```
1 || anything();
```

In this case, anything() will never execute, because || can simply return as soon as it evaluates the 1; no matter what anything()'s return value, the return value of || in this expression can *never* be 0.

Similarly:

```
0 && anything_else();
```

Here, anything_else() will never execute, because && already knows that its value can never be anything *but* 0.

In your examples, the ++ preincrements don't actually affect the short-circuiting, except to hide the values that the boolean short-circuit operators are *actually* making their decisions on.

Answer (score 9):

The reason is that `&&` and `||` short circuit.

That is, once they know what the end result of the boolean expression will be, they stop evaluating.

So, if you do `1 || x++`, then `x` will never be incremented, because any non-zero boolean value is a true value.

Likewise, if you do `0 && x++`, `x++` never will get executed either.

See also:

- [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer to your questions is that if you have the code `A||B` 
If A evaluates to true then B is NEVER evaluated.

So in your first case if ++x is true (in your case x==2 so it is true) then the rest of the expression is never evaluated

Similarly in the second case ++x evaluates to  0 which is false thus the second art of the expression ++y must be evaluated (and this also evaluates to 0 which is false); no wis a similar manner to the || operator if the first operand of the && operator is false then there is no need to evaluate the second operand - thus the third term is never evaluated.

The same logic can be applied to the third case.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way c short-circuits the `||` and `&&` operators.

For example, if you have `A && B`, the program will evaluate `A`. If that turns out to be false, we already know the result will be false no matter what's in `B`, so `B` is never evaluated. If you have `C || D` and `C` evaluates to true, you know the result is true no matter what's in `D`, so `D` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, the increments of variables are used in conjugation with expressions.
This is to avoid using if-else structure.

Here is the examples where precedence of operators are clarified:

```
++x || (++y && ++z);

++x || (++y && ++z);

(++x && ++y) || ++z;

(++x && ++y) || ++z;
```

the expressions are evaluated from left to right.
In the first example, the program already know the whole expression will yield true after ++x, and the program will not bother to evaluate the rest of the expression. C uses something called short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ or C:

True is 1 or any non-zero value

False is 0 or any negative value

These conditions are short-circuited - so when C++/C comes across the first true part - it breaks and doesn't evaluate the rest.

```
x = y = z = 1;
++x || ++y && ++z;
printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
//op  :   x = 2    y = 1  z = 1 
//why is 'x' only incrementd?
```

x is true (2) and the rest of the condition is not evaluated

```
x = y = z = -1;
++x || ++y && ++z;
printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
//op  :  x = 0    y = 0  z = -1
//why are 'x' and 'y' incremented?
```

x is false (0) so then y is evaluated which is false (0) - since it is false it is not checked further..

```
x = y = z = 1;
++x && ++y || ++z;
printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
//op  : x = 2    y = 2  z = 1
//why is 'x' only incrementd?
```

x is true (2 which is non zero) 
y is true (2) - since x and y are true - the first part is true so it doesnt evaluate z.

```
x = y = z = -1;
++x && ++y || ++z;
printf ("x = %d\t y = %d\tz = %d\n", x, y, z);
//op  : x = 0    y = -1 z = 0
//why are 'x' and 'z' incremented?
```

it is evaluated as (x && y) || z
x is evaluated and it is false (0)
z is then evaluated and it is false(0)
the result of this condition is actually false.

I may be completely wrong but's how I understand this.
Hope it helps..

Comment: You say that `true` is a non-zero value and in the next sentence say that `false` can be a negative value, which is also non-zero. Zero is always considered `false` in C and C++. C++ also have the `bool` type built-in, and `false` in C++ is not the same as the integer `0`.